# Iterate through every row from a SELECT

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

So I have a table for example with 2 cols and 3 rows.
I now want to go for example through every row from my table with a SELECT.

Like this:

```
IS
   v_text1 VARCHAR
   v_text2 VARCHAR
BEGIN
   SELECT text, ohterText INTO v_text1, v_text2 FROM table;
   v_text1 := v_text1 || ' ' || v_text2;
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_text1);
```

I tried putting a FOR LOOP around it that counts rows and then would output a row with ROWNR but that didn't work.
In general, I want the same logic for the entire SELECT and all its rows.
Any advice?

Comment: study more about `cursor`

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! In general, if you plan using loops in your SQL query, you are doing something wrong. Please provide example data and desired result here, so we can help you with the query fo accomplish that.

Answer (score 0):

The way you put it, you don't have to declare any variables because everything can be done as

```
begin
  for cur_r in (select text ||' '|| othertext as result from your_table) loop
    dbms_output.put_line(cur_r.result);
  end loop;
end;
```

Loop is here because you want to fetch *all* rows from that table. If you don't do it in a loop, Oracle will raise TOO_MANY_ROWS error as you can't fit all rows into scalar variables.